# Trouble with nvd3 date-data line chart

Tags: d3.js, charts, line, nvd3.js

I am quite new in D3 and nvd3. I am trying to plot a graph with date axis and data axis - https://jsfiddle.net/sujit77/7ns2g4a1/6/.

```
var dataValue = [{'key':'Line', 'values':[{"key":"2016-04-04 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-04-05 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-04-07 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-04-08 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-04-11 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-04-13 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-04-14 0:0:0","value":0.5},{"key":"2016-04-19 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-04-20 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-04-22 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-04-25 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-04-26 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-04-27 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-04-28 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-04-29 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-05-03 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-05-04 0:0:0","value":0},{"key":"2016-05-06 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-05-09 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-05-10 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-05-11 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-05-12 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-05-13 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-05-16 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-05-17 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-05-19 0:0:0","value":1},{"key":"2016-05-24 0:0:0","value":0},{"key":"2016-05-25 0:0:0","value":0.5},{"key":"2016-05-26 0:0:0","value":1}]}];

nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart()
  //.showControls(false)
  //.showMaxMin(false);
  .x(function(d) {return d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse(d['key']);})

  var format = d3.time.format("%m %d %Y");

  chart.yAxis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

  chart.xAxis
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%Y %b %d')(new Date(d)) });

  d3.select('#line-charts').append('svg')
    .attr('height', 250)
    .attr('width', 400)
    .datum(dataValue)
    .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
  return chart;
});
```

I am not able to plot the graph which should have been generated using the sample data. I am getting following error in browser's console window -

> Error:  attribute transform: Trailing garbage, "translate(0,NaN)".

Along with that I am trying to hide the bottom scale and min-max value in X-axis using ".showControls(false)" and ".showMaxMin(false)". But those are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to do the y accessor.

Do something like:
`chart.y(function (d) { return d.value; });`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I also found that I can remove bottom "nv-context" (the second bottom graph) by using ".lineChart()" instead of using ".lineWithFocusChart()".